# How important is to call dispose on a WCF ChannelFactory<T> and T channel object right after usage?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, oop

Developers like to write as short and simple code as possible. We are invoking WCF services in C# and wondering if the following intuition is right or wrong.
One way of using `ChannelFactory` code is:

```
var factory = new ChannelFactory<IService>("Endpoint");
var client = factory.CreateChannel();

client.DoSomething();

((IClientChannel)client).Close();
factory.Close();
```

Other way (a bit cleaner) is using a wrapper object (for factory and channel) which implements `IDisposable` where disposes both and used in using block:

```
using (ServiceWrapper<IService> svcWrapper = new ServiceWrapper<IService>("Endpoint")) {
    svcWrapper.Channel.DoSomething();
}
```

Here, having to call the wrapper's property might be a bit annoying for developers. Basically also could be:

```
using (ServiceWrapper<IService> svcWrapper = new ServiceWrapper<IService>("Endpoint")) {
    IService client = svcWrapper.Channel;
    client.DoSomething();
}
```

(I also found [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx) saying that the using block can hide exceptions)

What the developers might prefer is:

```
 IService client = new ServiceWrapper<IService>("Endpoint").Channel;
 client.DoSomething();
```

From the book C# 5.0 in a Nutshell:

> A popular pattern is to have the finalizer call Dispose. This makes
>   sense when cleanup is non-urgent and hastening it by calling Dispose
>   is more of an optimization than a necessity.

If I add this to my `ServiceWrapper` (C# Finalize/Dispose pattern):

```
public void Dispose() {
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

~ServiceWrapper() {
    Dispose(false);
}
```

Then GC will eventually call Dispose and do the things that need to be done. i.e.:

```
public void Dispose(bool disposing) {
    if (disposing) {
        if (_channel != null) {
            ((IClientChannel)_channel).Close();
        }
        if (_factory != null) {
            _factory.Close();
        }

        _channel = null;
        _factory = null;
    }
}
```

I have a feeling that this is not a good practice to use with WCF `ChannelFactory<T>` and `T` channel, but I don't have a good explanation which would scare the developers away form using it. Can you guys explain pls?

I can't say it's not working, I tried it and it works fine. I can't see any noticeable performance difference or similar...
I cannot give other explanation than *"You don't know when the finalizer gets called."*
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, the only thing the `Dispose` method does is explicitly close the connection. That is all. You can see for yourself in the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/ChannelFactory.cs,198). Also, [`ClientBase<T>`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/ClientBase.cs,581), the base class for the connection does the same.

That said, if you call `Close` yourself there isn't an actual need at the moment to call `Dispose` at all, although I would argue that you really should `Dispose`, just to be future proof. Also this can be a fail-safe for errors occurring which may prevent `Close` to be called.

Comment: Thank you! This clears some mist. Is there a big danger in not manually calling the `Close` and letting the finalizer do it?

Comment: Besides keeping connections alive that should be close and mess up the memory on server and client? No. This is a good reason to close it as soon as possible though.

Comment: I see. By all means using the `Dispose` method (by call or by `using` block) would be the safest way. Thank you for your help! Any clarifications are still welcome.

Comment: @DDan  Dispose will call close that can throw. You should follow the link in your question using try{..}catch{..} pattern to release.